# Invisible JavaScript element that can't be clicked, why is the click event listener not working?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, console

I want to call the click function on a textarea on a specific website.

Usually when the user clicks the textarea it enters it, the placeholder "A little bit about you..." goes away and two buttons appear below the textarea: "Save" and "Cancel"

text area before the click:
[image]

text area after the click:
[image]

I tried everything to programatically execute that click but I just cannot get it to work.

Even more weird is that adding an eventListener to check which element is clicked doesn't log anything:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    console.log(event.target); 
}, true);
```

The above code works fine with all other elements and buttons on that website except the textarea.

the element doesn't have an ID so I target it with:

```
var targetElement = document.getElementsByClassName('textarea__input')[1];
```

now I tried calling `.focus()` and `.click()` on that element but nothing happens.

I even tried simulating a human like click:

```
var simulateMouseEvent = function (element, eventName, coordX, coordY) {
    element.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(eventName, {
        view: window,
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true,
        clientX: coordX,
        clientY: coordY,
        button: 0
    }));
};
var targetElement = document.getElementsByClassName('textarea__input')[1];
if (targetElement) {
        
        try {
            var box = targetElement.getBoundingClientRect(),
                coordX = box.left + (box.right - box.left) / 2,
                coordY = box.top + (box.bottom - box.top) / 2;

            simulateMouseEvent(targetElement, "mousedown", coordX, coordY);
            simulateMouseEvent(targetElement, "mouseup", coordX, coordY);
            simulateMouseEvent(targetElement, "click", coordX, coordY);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error clicking text button:", error);
        }
    }
```

Nothing works and the textarea only opens and shows the "Save" and "Cancel" button if I manually click on it.

Why is the eventListener not logging anything when I click that specific textarea?

Here is the HTML:

```
    <section class="settings-section is-opened" data-qa-role="settings-section-about">
   <header class="settings-section__header">
      <div class="settings-section__title" data-qa-role="settings-section-title">
         <h1 class="header-2"><span>About Me</span></h1>
      </div>
      <span class="settings-section__icon" role="presentation">
         <span class="icon icon--size-m settings-section__open-handler" role="presentation" data-qa-role="icon" data-qa-icon-name="generic-chevron-down">
            <svg data-origin="pipeline" viewBox="0 0 32 32" fill="none">
               <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M15.97 18.257l7.093-7.067a2.016 2.016 0 013.367.89c.188.691-.009 1.43-.516 1.937l-8.512 8.493a2.012 2.012 0 01-2.85 0l-8.513-8.493a1.994 1.994 0 01.049-2.778 2.013 2.013 0 012.788-.049l7.094 7.067z" fill="currentColor"></path>
            </svg>
         </span>
      </span>
   </header>
   <div class="settings-section__main" style="--settings-section-content-height:72px;">
      <div class="settings-section__content">
         <div class="settings-section__entry">
            <section class="settings-fieldset settings-fieldset--about" data-qa-role="about-fieldset">
               <div class="settings-fieldset__main">
                  <div class="settings-fieldset__field">
                     <div class="textarea has-autoheight has-placeholder" data-qa-role="profile-edit-about">
                        <div class="textarea__inner"><textarea class="textarea__input" placeholder="A little bit about you..." autocomplete="off" maxlength="300" dir="auto" style="height: 72px; min-height: 66px;">This is my teext</textarea><textarea class="textarea__ghost" aria-hidden="true" role="none"></textarea></div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </section>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

**UPDATE**
I think I found the problem, the website can detect that it's a click triggered by a script and not by a real human.
When I log the click:

```
const textarea = document.querySelector('.textarea__input');
textarea.addEventListener('click', event => {
  console.log('Click event triggered on textarea:', event);
});
```

This is what I get when I click manually:
[image]

and this is what I get when I call the .click() function via console:
[image]

ChatGPT says:
The isTrusted property is set to false, indicating that the event was generated by a script and not by a user action. This is a security feature of modern browsers that prevents malicious scripts from simulating user actions without the user's knowledge or consent.

But I also ready that websites don't have access to this "isTrusted" information.
Is there anything I can do to programmatically fire the same click event as when I manually click in the text area?

Comment: 1) Try targetElement.focus(), 2) Try document.execCommand, [example](/a/57900849).

Comment: You haven’t shown any html.  Maybe the text area is inside an iframe.  No way for us to tell.

Comment: @James I updated my question with the HTML code.
No iframe..

Comment: @wOxxOm that works with entering the text automatically but unfortunately still doesn't triggers a "click" that is needed to reveal the "Save" button.
I added pictures of that textarea element to my question to make it more clear what I'm refering to as the "Save" button

Comment: Does the code inside `if (targetElement) { … }` execute?

Comment: @James yes I just double checked and it gets executed

Comment: Isn't there a way to track exactly what happens when I click into the textarea? So I can just do exactly the same in code

Comment: It looks like there's only one `textarea__input` object, but you're getting the second one with `var targetElement = document.getElementsByClassName('textarea__input')[1];`. Unless your HTML is incomplete, try using `var targetElement = document.getElementsByClassName('textarea__input')[0];`

Comment: @JoeHerbert yes I only posted that specific part of the textarea, not the complete code

Comment: I think I found the problem, the website can detect that its a script executing the click.
I updated my question.

Comment: this (can) be website specific, I think a codesandbox or a live website where you execute the script would be nice if you could provide them

Comment: You can try adding a label for your textarea (`<label for="textarea-id">`) and call a click on that label. This might do the trick.

Comment: you don't know what the website is doing on click of the textarea, I suspect it might have a `click` handler of its own that calls `event.stopPropagation()`, which if so would explain why your handler attached to the `document` isn't getting triggered.

Comment: The provided code works fine aside from the wrong index: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ejyfus?file=index.ts please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Couldn't you just check how these buttons are toggled and rebuild it in a custom funtion.? It might be something as trivial as a class name toggle.

Comment: @ChrisHamilton Its on the website bumble.com when you set a bio in your profile.
Thats the texarea thats driving me insane haha

Answer (score 0):

isTrusted is read only property and can not be set programmatically.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted

Try using hasFocus() on textArea

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/hasFocus

Answer (score 0):

I see that the click event is getting fired, does it matter that the click event parameter gives a different value? You can call your function with the display buttons and placeholder text updation logic inside the event handler. What else are you actually looking for?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are trying to attach the event on before DOM is ready. You should bind/attach your event after the body tag or after DOM ready like below:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const textarea = document.querySelector('.textarea__input');
  textarea.addEventListener('click', event => {
    console.log('Click event triggered on textarea:', event);
  });
});
```

To catch dom ready by jquery;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  const textarea = document.querySelector('.textarea__input');
  textarea.addEventListener('click', event => {
    console.log('Click event triggered on textarea:', event);
  });
});
```

Comment: Here is jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/39Lrey2o/